# Eloquent querying relation based on main query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables:

- Users with column `id`
- Teams with column `id`
- Roles with column `id`
- Pivot `teams_users` with columns `team_id` `user_id` `role_id`

Goal: get teams, each team has members. Each member has a role in that team.

My approach:

Fetch teams, then fetch members and roles of that team. Loop the collection, add the role to the correct member, delete the role after.

```
$teams->each(function($team, $teamKey) use ($teams) {
                    if(empty($team->members) === false && empty($team->roles) === false) {
                        $team->members->each(function($member, $memberKey) use ($team) {
                            $team->roles->each(function($role) use ($member) {
                                if($member->id === $role->pivot->user_id) {
                                    $member->role = $role;
                                }
                            });
                        });

                    }
                });
```

My goal:

I want to do it using Eloquent and without looping the collection.

My `Team` model has two relations:

```
public function members() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "teams_users", "team_id", "user_id")->withPivot("role_id")->withTimestamps();
    }

public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, "teams_users", "team_id", "role_id")->withPivot("user_id")->withTimestamps();
    }
```

expected output should be like this:

```
{
    teams: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Awesome team",
            members: [
                {
                    id: 1
                    name: "Test",
                    role: {
                        id: 1,
                        title: "Admin"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you also post code in the "my approach" section?

Comment: The code needs to be "refined" but I have added it above.

Comment: Thank you. Yet, I still don't understand why you need to delete the role.

Comment: Oh, I meant deleting the `roles` relation because it's "useless" (after I fetch and loop the collection, I don't need it at all) but it's not a changing factor

Comment: Could you provide us with an example output of how the result might look (JSON or similar)?

Comment: I provided an example output. It's the same structure as the current one.